# Best way to save/load list of strings and the file will be manipulated by two Python scripts at the same time

Tags: python, json, string, list, pickle

I will create two Python scripts. One will generate strings and save them to a file. The other will traverse through the list of string from the top down, do operations on each string and then delete the string when done.

I would like to know which file type can best satisfy this purpose (e.g. pickle, json, plain text, csv,..)?

Comment: Why not a socket ? It seems you don' t really need a file.

Comment: If you need random access from both programs, an sqlite3 database might be an option.

Answer (score 1):

If the first script just writes the file once and then at some point the second script has to read it, I would use csv (or just plain text and the elements separated by a coma).

If the second file has to read periodically the strings that the first writes I would use a socket to send it to the second script.